Issue with Text Positioning and Custom Font "Angel Wish"
I'm encountering an issue with text positioning when using the custom font "Angel Wish." Even without applying any CSS, the text is positioned below the page. When I switch to a standard font like Arial, the problem does not occur. I've also tried adding an image with just HTML and CSS, but the issue persists.

Issues Encountered
Even without CSS, the text is positioned below the page.
The problem disappears when switching to standard fonts like Arial.
I have also tried adding an image with just HTML and CSS, but the issue persists.
Steps Taken
Verified that the "Angel Wish" font is being loaded correctly.
Tested with standard fonts, and the issue does not occur.
Used browser developer tools to check applied styles.
Added an image using only HTML and CSS, but the issue is still present.
Request
How can I resolve the text positioning issue with the "Angel Wish" font? Any suggestions?


p {
  font-family: 'Angel Wish', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 40px;
}
<link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/angel-wish" rel="stylesheet">
You need to scroll down:
<p>test</p>




The snippet here is not able to reproduce the issue for me; tested in Chrome on Mac.

It certainly shows the issue for me. The text is half a page further down from the top. I cannot fix it using line height or overflow or resetting. The inspect shows the container at the top and the actual text way down the page

I confirm that it looks weird both on Chrome and FF (on Windows) where the <p> earns a big height.. the font type has surely wrong metrics and needs to be fixed. If you try to download the woff file and upload it to https://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html you will see for example a very huge value on OS/2 and Windows Metrics table > usWinAscent as 59624..  the solution is for sure fixing the woff.. in the meantime you may use something like transform: translateY(-1200px); on the element

I have noticed after inspecting the page that when Angel Wish font is applied then there is a height: 2384.67px and width: 990.667px set to that container. But when I tried to fix the height then it didn't change anything. You can also notice in Computed section of developer tools.

Line height changes the numbers but not the result

the code here doesn't happen to me, and looks fine. Safari on Mac

Thanks to @Diego D's investigations the answer is:  1. don't use this font  source - it's badly compiled 2. don't use cdnfonts.com - they list quite a few questionable fonts in terms of quality and respected licenses. Besides, the CDN file delivery is sluggish – just load the fonts locally (as a GDPR affected designer I can confirm: It works fine even compared to google's infrastructure) 3. you may find a better source of this file (e.g from the designers directly or a more trustworthy repository)
